# Cryptic for-loop update statements

Tags: c, idioms

The code I have has the following loops:

```
for (i = A[x]; i < N; i = i | (i + 1))
```

and,

```
for (i = A[x]; i >= 0; i = (i & (i + 1)) -1 )
```

I don't really understand these update statements. Are these clever ways of doing something trivial?

Comment: How are `A`, `B`, and `N` defined?

Comment: They are integers, I think their items are indices to some array. N is the size of that array.

Comment: Somebody has job security issues

Comment: The first is dead easy: start from a power of 2 and it generates successively longer bit masks. The second does nothing useful I can see. Are you sure you have it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When code confuses you, experiment on it.

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 256; i = i | (i + 1))
    printf(" %04x", i);
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
$ gcc -std=c99 test.c
$ ./a.out
0000 0001 0003 0007 000f 001f 003f 007f 00ff
```

So the first expression that confuses you (`i = i | (i + 1)`) is constructing successive bitmasks from the bottom bit upward.

You can use the same technique to determine what the second expression does.

Comment: The first is easy, the second not so. Care to have a go?

Comment: @david.pfx I am ~75% sure the second one doesn't do what it was intended to do (since it seems to go into an infinite loop on most inputs) and without more information from the OP I don't think I can usefully speculate on what it was *intended* to do.

Comment: As long as it's a signed int it should terminate after 2 or 3 iterations, but the values seem meaningless. Obviously if it's unsigned it cannot terminate.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, lets check what it does if `i` is initially zero:

First iteration `i` is zero, binary `0000`. Then you come to the update expression which does a bitwise OR between the zero and zero plus one: `0000 | 0001`, resulting in the value `1`.

The second iteration we have `0001` and oring it with `2` (binary `0010`) resulting in `3` (`0011`).

The third iteration you have `0011` (i.e. the value `3`) which you or with `0100` (value `4` which is `3+1`) resulting in `0111` (i.e. value `7`).

It continues like this, setting all bits from the least significant bit to the most.

Comment: `0111` equals 7... this doesn't loop infinitely.